# How do I determine the Top/Left of a Telerik RadTileViewItem control in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik

I'm using a Telerik RadTileView control in a .Net C# WPF application.

I'm creating a WPF popup window that I'd like to position relative to a RadTileViewItem within the tile view.

I would like to find the **Top** and **Left** position of a **RadTileViewItem** control.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: To the left and the top relative to what?

Comment: Spawn:  The RadTileView parent container is in a <grid>, so the position relative to that grid is what I'm looking for.